# Three.js fast text engraving

Tags: javascript, 3d, three.js

I'm trying to engrave some text on a surface using Three.js. I've achieved it using [csg.js](https://evanw.github.io/csg.js/) and [ThreeCSG](https://github.com/chandlerprall/ThreeCSG) and it works perfect, the result is really good but the problem is it takes a lot of time. On my PC it takes about 30 seconds to engrave the word `Hello`.

Searching for other solution I found [this](https://www.troupejewelry.com/customproduct) site. They make custom jewelry and you can engrave text on it and the time it takes to engrave the text is really short! So I assume they are not using csg.js. What other technique can be used to achieve this result?

I though about using bump maps, I should generate a bump map for each letter but I don't know if that's the correct approach.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I can see by looking at the shaders that the site your linked to uses bump maps.

I don't think you would create a bump map for each letter, you would just do all the drawing (text) on a single canvas and apply that as a bump map.

Click on "Run Code Snippet" below for a demo of canvas bump maps (click and drag in the white box).
I hope this helps.

```js
var camera, scene, renderer, mesh, material, stats;
var drawStartPos = {x:0, y:0};

init();
setupCanvasDrawing();
animate();

function init() {
    // Renderer.
    renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
    //renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio);
    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
    // Add renderer to page
    document.getElementById('threejs-container').appendChild(renderer.domElement);

    // Create camera.
    camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(70, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 1000);
    camera.position.z = 400;

    // Create scene.
    scene = new THREE.Scene();

    // Create material
    material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial();

    // Create cube and add to scene.
    var geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(200, 200, 200);
    mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
    scene.add(mesh);

    // Create ambient light and add to scene.
    var light = new THREE.AmbientLight(0x404040); // soft white light
    scene.add(light);

    // Create directional light and add to scene.
    var directionalLight = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffffff);
    directionalLight.position.set(1, 1, 1).normalize();
    scene.add(directionalLight);

    // Add listener for window resize.
    window.addEventListener('resize', onWindowResize, false);

    // Add stats to page.
    stats = new Stats();
    document.body.appendChild( stats.dom );
}

function setupCanvasDrawing() {
  // get canvas and context
  var drawingCanvas = document.getElementById('drawing-canvas');
    var drawingContext = drawingCanvas.getContext('2d');
    
    // draw white background
    drawingContext.fillStyle = "#FFFFFF";
    drawingContext.fillRect(0,0,128,128);
    
    // set canvas as bumpmap
    material.bumpMap = new THREE.Texture(drawingCanvas);
    
    // set the variable to keep track of when to draw
    var paint = false;
    
    // add canvas event listeners
    drawingCanvas.addEventListener('mousedown', function(e){
      paint = true
      drawStartPos = {x:e.offsetX, y:e.offsetY};
    });
    drawingCanvas.addEventListener('mousemove', function(e){
     if(paint){
       draw(drawingContext, e.offsetX, e.offsetY);
      }
    });
    drawingCanvas.addEventListener('mouseup', function(e){
      paint = false;
    });
    drawingCanvas.addEventListener('mouseleave', function(e){
      paint = false;
    });
}

// Draw function
function draw(drawContext, x, y) {
  drawContext.moveTo(drawStartPos.x, drawStartPos.y);
 drawContext.lineTo(x,y);
 drawContext.stroke();
  drawStartPos = {x:x, y:y};
  material.bumpMap.needsUpdate = true;
}

function animate() {
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
    mesh.rotation.x += 0.005;
    mesh.rotation.y += 0.01;
    renderer.render(scene, camera);
    stats.update();
}

function onWindowResize() {
    camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
    camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
}
```

```css
body {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

#drawing-canvas {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #000;
  top: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  z-index: 3;
}

#threejs-container {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://rawgit.com/mrdoob/three.js/r83/build/three.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/mrdoob/stats.js/r17/build/stats.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="drawing-canvas" height="128" width="128"></canvas>
<div id="threejs-container"></div>
```

Comment: Really interesting example.  I'd even argue that it should be one of the examples shipped with three.js!

Comment: That's AWESOME! I didn't event know you could use a canvas context as a texture. Thank you very much, it's exactly what I need! You should really propose it to be added to the three.js examples as @LuisE.Fraguada says.

Comment: [HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/2pha/e6rbt3r4/) is an example of combining 2 images on a canvas before adding them as diffuse map on a material that you might find interesting.

Comment: I created a [pull request to add this to the three.js examples](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/pull/11013) if your interested.

Comment: It is now in the official examples :)
https://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_materials_texture_canvas